# Drush cc gives only two options even when I am in root folder

Tags: mysql, drupal, drush

I am working with drupal 8, MAMP version 3.5, and drush version 8.1.3. I have installed drush globally and when I enter `drush st` it gives me information but when I run `drush cc`, it gives me only two options

1. cancel
2. drush

whereas, it is suppose to give me many options. I am in a root folder of the site I am working on .i.e. `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysites/mysite`. My OS is OSX on macbook pro, just in case if this is mac specific issue.

Done with this step as well:

`sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql /var/mysql`

Not sure what else to look into, can you anyone please guide?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though drush doesn't think you're in a site directory.  If you are in a multisite directory, go into sites/www.yoursite.com and try drush cc from there -- you should see all of your options.